# How to implement generic interfaces with submodules in Fortran?

Tags: module, fortran, procedure, gfortran

My problem is that I have two generic procedures implemented each one in 'mod1.f08' and 'mod2.f08'.

```
! mod1.f08
MODULE mod1

   INTERFACE func1
      procedure :: foo_int, foo_real
...

! mod2.f08
MODULE mod2

   INTERFACE func2
      procedure :: bar_int, bar_real
...
```

But I want to join both as submodules of only one module, in this way:

```
! mod1.f08
MODULE (mainmodule) mod1

   INTERFACE func1
      procedure :: foo_int, foo_real
...

! mod2.f08
MODULE (mainmodule) mod2

   INTERFACE func2
      procedure :: bar_int, bar_real
...

! mainmodule.f08
MODULE mainmodule

    INTERFACE
       procedure :: func1
       procedure :: func2
    END INTERFACE
    ...
```

Is it possible to do something like this?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about your issue?  The usual method would be to put the `INTERFACE` information in a module within a file and the implementation details in the submodule in a different file.

Comment: I edited the question. I want is only to use submodules to join some generic procedures that are very huge to put all only in one or two files.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you intend to achieve?

```
module Main_mod

    interface
    module subroutine foo(dummyReal)
        real, intent(in) :: dummyReal
    end subroutine foo
    end interface

    interface
    module subroutine bar(dummyInt)
        integer, intent(in) :: dummyInt
    end subroutine bar
    end interface

    interface genericFunc
        module procedure :: foo, bar
    end interface genericFunc

end module Main_mod

submodule (Main_mod) SubMain1_smod
contains
    module subroutine foo(dummyReal)
        real, intent(in) :: dummyReal
        write(*,"(*(g0,:,' '))") "This is from inside foo @SubMain1_smod: dummyReal = ", dummyReal
    end subroutine foo
end submodule SubMain1_smod

submodule (Main_mod) SubMain2_smod
contains
    module subroutine bar(dummyInt)
        integer, intent(in) :: dummyInt
        write(*,"(*(g0,:,' '))") "This is from inside bar @SubMain2_smod: dummyInt = ", dummyInt
    end subroutine bar
end submodule SubMain2_smod

program hello
    use Main_mod, only: genericFunc
   call genericFunc(1.)
   call genericFunc(1)
end program Hello
```

Here is a test output:

```
> ifort main.f90 -o run.exe
Intel(R) Visual Fortran Intel(R) 64 Compiler for applications running on Intel(R) 64, Version 19.0.4.245 Build 20190417
Copyright (C) 1985-2019 Intel Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.22.27905.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

-out:run.exe
-subsystem:console
main.obj

> run.exe
This is from inside foo @SubMain1_smod: dummyReal =  1.000000
This is from inside bar @SubMain2_smod: dummyInt =  1
```

The generic procedures have to have their interfaces in the main module and the implementation goes inside the submodules. If the procedure implementations are too large, I'd separate the submodules from the main module and put them in separate files. This will also avoid the compilation cascade by `make` software if any changes only occur to the submodules and not the interfaces in the main module. (I do it in general for any submodule size). If the procedure interfaces are also too large (with too many dummy input/output arguments), you could also avoid duplicate interface for each of the procedures (once in the main module and the other inside the submodules in the implementation of the procedures) via the `procedure` keyword in the submodules like the following,

```
module Main_mod

    interface
    module subroutine foo(dummyReal)
        real, intent(in) :: dummyReal
    end subroutine foo
    end interface

    interface
    module subroutine bar(dummyInt)
        integer, intent(in) :: dummyInt
    end subroutine bar
    end interface

    interface genericFunc
        module procedure :: foo, bar
    end interface genericFunc

end module Main_mod

submodule (Main_mod) SubMain1_smod
contains
    module procedure foo
        write(*,"(*(g0,:,' '))") "This is from inside foo @SubMain1_smod: dummyReal = ", dummyReal
    end procedure foo
end submodule SubMain1_smod

submodule (Main_mod) SubMain2_smod
contains
    module procedure bar
        write(*,"(*(g0,:,' '))") "This is from inside bar @SubMain2_smod: dummyInt = ", dummyInt
    end procedure bar
end submodule SubMain2_smod

program hello
    use Main_mod, only: genericFunc
   call genericFunc(1.)
   call genericFunc(1)
end program Hello
```

This will generate an identical binary, but the implementation is shorter. However, I personally do not like it, as it often requires you to look at the parent module (which is typically in a separate file) for any dummy argument information. I hope that I understood your question correctly.

Comment: Thank you King, you understanded the main idea. But as you show in last code, to get togheter all procedures and so create the generic procedure, its complex. My idea was to create generic procedures on separate submodules to join on a only one module.
The other alternative is include modules with this generic procedures on a main module with "use" clause. Its much more simple, but i dont shure if its ideal.

Comment: I believe that's as simple as it can be made. The more concise solution would be to put all of the routines into a single parent module and avoid duplicate interfaces for both the parent module and submodules. If the implementation of the two routines is the same, you could also merge the implementations into a single file and `include` their implementations where they are needed in the module, but that's ugly and potentially dangerous. I don't think if there is any simpler solution in any other low-level language (including C/C++) than what is doable in Fortran, either.